# What are some currencies that are not pegged and fixed?

Tags: currency, exchange-rates

Are there any currencies that are not pegged to the dollar or euro and are purely fixed exchange rates?

Comment: What do you mean by "purely fixed exchange rates"? What are they fixed to? All currencies?

Answer (score 1):

According to the table from [this website](https://www.thebalance.com/fixed-exchange-rate-definition-pros-cons-examples-3306257), these are countries that peg their currencies to the Euro:

- Bosnia and Herzegovina
- Bulgaria
- Comoros
- Denmark
- Sao Tome and Principe

Other than these, Bhutan fixes their exchange rate to the Indian rupee, Lesotho and Namibia fix their exchange rates to the South African rand.